# How to add multiple labels to contour lines using clabels

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to plot a contour map in matplotlib. I want the labels to be printed at a certain interval in the plot for more clarity, but I am unable to do so. How can I do that?

The following [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) plot has multiple labels per contour lines:

[image: MATLAB]

However, in [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib), I get only one label per contour line.

[image: matplotlib]

How can I get multiple labels in matplotlib?

Answer (score 2):

You can just apply the label again:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
ax.clabel(CS, [-1, 0.5,], inline=1, fontsize=10)
ax.clabel(CS, [0.5,], inline=1, fontsize=10)
```

This will give you two labels on the contour with te level 0.5. I don't quite see a way to control their position, but as far as I can see, they seem to be spaced evenly automatically. Here is the output wth the data generated as per [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contour-demo-py) link.

[image: Two contour levels]

Comment: Woah...This totally works! I was stuck at this for so long, and it is such a simple workaround. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer provided by @krm, you can use `manual` option to set contour labels' location. The relevant code is:-

```
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
manual_locations = [(-1, -1.4), (-0.62, -0.7), (-2, 0.5), (1.7, 1.2), (2.0, 1.4)]
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10, manual=manual_locations)
```